# android cannot reach iis server timeout error

Tags: android, asp.net, iis

I am working on an android app on my Mac OS (host) and I have set up a VirtualBox VM with Windows 8.1.

On the virtual machine I have and asp.net web API set up IIS listening on port 8080.

From the host I can browse from chrome or request with postman, for example, to the web API home page (http://vmstaticip:8080/api/auth/example) which returns a JSON

The problem I have is that when I try to make a `GET` request to the API, it gives a timeout error, like it isn't reaching the IIS server.

http request:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://vmstaticip:8080/api/auth/" + idToken, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {...
```

I have searched but could not found anything regarding what can be causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by changing my adapter config in the vm from host-only to bridge adapter (see vbox docs)